# C++ - Unable to convert from std::basic string<char> to bool

Tags: c++, vector, casting, io, stdstring

I am trying to build a simple authentication mechanism whereby the user inputs his login credentials and his input is then compared to content in a file 'UserDB.txt'. However, when i try to iterate through the file and compare his credentials with all the lines in the file, the following error occurs :

```
main.cpp:86:38: error: could not convert ‘credential.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >((*(const std::basic_string<char>*)str.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >(((std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::size_type)i))))’ from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘bool’
```

Here is my code :

```
std::cout << "\nEnter Username: " << endl;
std::getline(std::cin,username);
std::cout << "\nEnter password: " << endl;
std::getline(std::cin,password);

credential=username + ":" + password; //Concatenates the credentials into one variable


std::fstream myFile("UserDB.txt");
if (myFile.is_open())
{
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> iter(myFile), end;
    std::vector<std::string> str(iter, end);

    // print contents
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << str[i] << std::endl;
        if (credential=str[i]) //Error occurs here
        {
            cout << "Credentials accepted!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Login fail! Wrong credentials..." << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I know I probably shouldn't be using the -fpermissive flag in g++ as it would probably come back and bite me in the ass later on. So how do I avoid this problem in the first place?

Comment: Do you not notice anything strange with the line the compiler is giving you?

Comment: `credential==str[i]`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Nope tried that already, doesn't work

Comment: What is the type of `credential`?

Comment: The variable str is a std::vector<std::string>. Maybe a change in the way i store lines in the file in it is in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its ok I found a work around...

```
std::cout << "\nEnter Username: " << endl;
            std::getline(std::cin,username);
            std::cout << "\nEnter password: " << endl;
            std::getline(std::cin,password);
            credential=username + ":" + password; //Concatenates the credentials into one variable
            std::cout << "Variable credential is :" + credential;

string array[50]; // creates array to hold names
            short loop=0; //short for loop for input
            string line; //this will contain the data read from the file
            ifstream myfile ("UserDB.txt"); //opening the file.
            if (myfile.is_open()) //if the file is open
            {
                while (! myfile.eof() ) //while the end of file is NOT reached
                {
                    getline (myfile,line); //get one line from the file
                    array[loop] = line;
                    //cout << "\n";
                    //cout << loop << ":" << array[loop] << endl; //and output it

                    if (credential==array[loop])
                    {
                        cout << "Login successful!";

                        displayMenu();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Login failed...
                        loop++;
                    }




                }

                myfile.close(); //closing the file
            }
    else cout << "Unable to open file"; //if the file is not open output
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change `credential=str[i]` to `credential==str[i]`.  You need the double = or its going to try to set `credentials` equal to `str[i]`

Comment: I wonder if the OP has any warnings enabled... `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: I tried it already. I get this error : main.cpp:86:37: error: name lookup of ‘i’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping [-fpermissive]